# Why ShowRuler tool is removed from Internet Explorer 9 version

Tags: internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

As per my project design strategy we recieve the style guide with specifications from the UX Team.
We design the screen accordingly. "Show Ruler" tool was very useful when we design in IE8 Browser version.
Just wanted to know why Microsoft stopped shipping that from IE9.
Please do let me know if there are any other addons for IE alone.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The ruler tool is still in IE9 and IE10 :) 
Just open the DevTools and press Ctrl+L

That said, the F12 developer tools were completely revamped in IE11 and we did not get a chance to implement the ruler tool. It's good to know you found it useful. I'll make sure the F12 team gets your feedback!